# Change web reference IP in C# asp.net web forms project

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-reference

I'm working on a project that was not created by me. This project contains a web reference to some windows service that is run on a remote machine.

In Visual Studio 2010 it looks like this:

[image]

I used VS's search to get the IP in the solution and see it in 5 places in a project. Also, it seems there is code in 3 places (others are is web.config and config.config files) with the IP reference that were generated by Visual Studio.

I have never used web references - is it possible to change the IP pointing to this web service without recompiling?

Comment: what about web.config file. is there any entry about this web service client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you have to change the proxy URL to be dynamic. Then, you'll be able to access it via your application's configuration files.

[This post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic) on CodeProject should explain it pretty well for you.